# How to set different values concatenated as a dictionary key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a tab separated file (no file extension) that looks like this:

```
#something

#something
#something
#something
CHROM   POS1    POS2    IN_FILE REF1    REF2    ALT1    ALT2
chr1    9997    .       1       N       .       <NON_REF>       .
chr1    .       10000   2       .       N       .       <NON_REF>
chr1    .       10009   2       .       A       .       <NON_REF>
chr1    10010   .       1       C       .       <NON_REF>       .
chr1    10012   .       1       C       .       <NON_REF>       .
chr1    10015   10015   B       A       A       <NON_REF>       <NON_REF>
chr1    .       10016   2       .       C       .       <NON_REF>
chr1    10017   .       1       C       .       <NON_REF>       .
chr1    10018   .       1       C       .       <NON_REF>       .
```

I need from this file to create a dictionary that stores as key the first three columns and as values the 4th,5ht and 6th columns, so the output would look like this, (I also have to get rid of the hashtags from the header):

```
my_dict = {chr1\t9997\t.: 1\tN\t. , chr1\t.\t10000: 2\t.\tN , chr1\t.\t10009 : 2\t.\tN , chr1\t10010\t. :  1\tC\t. ...}
```

My code:

```
with open ("/Users//dummy2", 'r') as f:
    rows = ( line.split('\t') for line in f )
    d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
```

Outputs:

```
{'#something\n': [],
 '\n': [],
 'CHROM': ['POS1', 'POS2', 'IN_FILE', 'REF1', 'REF2', 'ALT1', 'ALT2\n'],
 'chr1': ['10018', '.', '1', 'C', '.', '<NON_REF>', '.\n']}
```

I would like to get rid of the # tags and have as a key the three first values of each line.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your code really giving the output you are showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import re

with open ("/Users//dummy2", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [l.strip() for l in lines] # remove newlines

# get rid of '#' tag lines
lines = [l for l in lines if l and l[0]!='#']

# split the lines
data = [ re.split(' +',line) for line in lines]

# Create dictonary
_dict = { '\t'.join(d[:3]):'\t'.join(d[3:6]) for d in data[1:] }
```

Answer (score 1):

For each line you read, filter it out if it starts with '#' or '\n' (blank line)
by using the condition `if line[0] not in '#\n'`.

When constructing a dictionary, split the row using 'slicing', but a list can't be used as a key, so you must convert it to a `tuple`.

Final result:

```py
with open ("/Users//dummy2", 'r') as f:
    rows = ( line.split('\t') for line in f if line[0] not in '#\n')
    d = { tuple(row[:3]):row[3:] for row in rows}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it